# My WordPress menu based on Twitter bootstrap creates menu-item and not page-item

Tags: menus, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a dynamic menu being generated, but instead of generating a **page-item** it generates a **menu-item**. What I would like it to do is generate page-items and all the rest of it so that I can show or highlight the current page a user is visiting.

my code is :

```
// header.php

<?php // Loading WordPress Custom Menu
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse',
        'menu_class'      => 'nav navbar-nav',
        'menu_id'         => 'main-menu',
        'walker'          => new Cwd_wp_bootstrapwp_Walker_Nav_Menu()
) ); ?>
```

And then in the functions.php I have

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'cwd_wp_bootstrapwp_theme_setup' );
if ( ! function_exists( 'cwd_wp_bootstrapwp_theme_setup' ) ):
function cwd_wp_bootstrapwp_theme_setup() {
    // Adds the main menu
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'main-menu' => __( 'Main Menu', 'cwd_wp_bootstrapwp' ),
    ) );
}
endif;
```

Comment: Do you mean highlight the menu item in the menu?

Comment: Yes, so if you're on the blog page highlight the menu item that says blog.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of CSS code which works with one specific theme.

You may need to change the classes depending on your theme.

```
.nav-primary .current-menu-item > a  {
color: blue;
background-color: white;
}
```

This will highlight the background color of the current menu item to white and you can also change the font color which in this case is blue.